# "Pour qui" and "pour ceux qui" - what's the difference?

Tags: sens, pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées

> "pour **qui** n'est pas un habitué des lieux"
>
> "pour **ceux qui** ne sont pas des habitués des lieux"

The first construct is not familiar to me. Do both have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The first phrase is equivalent to:

> *pour **celui** qui n'est pas un habitué des lieux.*

You can then see that the meaning is essentially the same, the only difference being that the first one is singular while the second one is plural.

> *for **someone** not familiar with the place.*
>
> *for **those** not familiar with the place.*